# Dominated convergence theorem for spectral measure

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

Okay, I posed my question maybe a little bit to vague:

What I have in mind is the following:

Let $L$ be a generator of a semigroup $(P_t)_{t \ge 0}$ with $\langle x,Lx \rangle \le 0$ defined on $D(L) = \{ f ; \lim_{t \downarrow 0} \frac{P_tf-f}{t} \text{ exists}\}.$

Now, assume that $L$ is self-adjoint on this domain, so 
$$L = \int_{0}^{\infty} - \lambda dE.$$

Then I claim that the $P_t \in L(H)$ can be written as $P_t:= \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\lambda t} dE.$

Now, I want to show that by this definition of $P_t$ I can actually recover $L$ in the following sense:

$$\frac{\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\lambda t} dE(f)-\int_{0}^{\infty} dE(f)}{t}$$ exists (for $t \downarrow 0$)if and only if $f \in D(L)$ and equals in this case $L(f).$

I think everybody is tempted to differentiate under the integral sign, but I am not sure how to make this rigorous.

Comment: Integrable with respect to what? There are many integrals possible, one for each $x$. For example $\|T_n x\|^{2}=\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f_n(\lambda)|^{2}d\|E(\lambda)x\|^{2}$

Comment: @TrialAndError: I think it would be sufficient if $g$ is integrable w.r.t. the total variation of the measure $E$.

Comment: @gerw : What is your definition of total variation of the spectral measure $E$?

Comment: As usual: $|E|(A) = \sup_{\pi} \sum_{B \in \pi} \|E(B)\|$ and the supremum ranges over all finite partitions of $A$ into pairwise disjoint measurable sets, see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation#Total_variation_norm_of_vector-valued_measures.

Comment: @gerw : $\|E(B)\|=1$ if $E(B)\ne 0$. I think you have to stick with convergence that is appropriate for any measure. Bounded convergence, of Borel functions, for example, to a Borel function. Or $g$ has to be integrable with respect to every measure $\mu_{x}(B)=\|E(B)x\|^{2}$.

Comment: Oh, yes. Not many $g$ are integrable in this case and my comment appears to be useless.

Comment: @TrialAndError I updated the question in a more hopefully more clear way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference you have is deceptively singular. For $f\in \mathcal{D}(A)$,
$$
        \frac{1}{t}\left[\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\lambda t}dE(\lambda)f-\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\lambda t}dE(\lambda)f\right]-\int_{0}^{\infty}(-\lambda)dE(\lambda)f \\
      =\int_{0}^{\infty}\left[\frac{e^{-\lambda t}-1}{t}+\lambda\right]dE(\lambda)f \\
      =\int_{0}^{\infty}\left[-\int_{0}^{\lambda}e^{-\mu t}d\mu+\lambda\right]dE(\lambda)f \\
      =\int_{0}^{\infty}\left[\int_{0}^{\lambda}(1-e^{-\mu t})d\mu\right] dE(\lambda)f
$$
Therefore,
$$
       \left\|\frac{1}{t}\{P(t)-I\}f-(-A)f\right\|^{2}
          =\int_{0}^{\infty}\left|\frac{1}{\lambda}\int_{0}^{\lambda}(1-e^{-\mu t})d\mu\right|^{2}\lambda^{2}d\|E(\lambda)f\|^{2}
$$
Now you can use dominated convergence because
$$
                \|Af\|^{2} = \int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda^{2}d\|E(\lambda)f\|^{2} < \infty,
$$
and because the following remains uniformly bounded by $1$ for $\lambda\in (0,\infty)$ and converges pointwise everywhere to $0$ on $(0,\infty)$ as $t\downarrow 0$:
$$
     \left|\frac{1}{\lambda}\int_{0}^{\lambda}(1-e^{-\mu t})d\mu\right|^{2}
$$
There is an issue if $E\{0\}f \ne 0$, but that extra part is handled easily and separately.

Comment: ah, so here we only use the dominated convergence theorem for standard Borel measures, as $\mu_x:=\langle Ex,x,\rangle$ is one, right?

Comment: By the way: If I knew that my $C_0$ semigroup $(P_t)_t$ consists of bounded self-adjoint operator $P_t \in L(H),$ does this conversely imply that the generator $L$ is self-adjoint, too. The converse is a consequence of the spectral theorem as I was just trying to show. But do you know if the impliciation $P_t$ s.a. then $L$ too, also holds?

Comment: Let's see. If $(P(t)x,y)=(x,P(t)y)$ for all $t \ge 0$, then $(P'(0)x,y)=(x,P'(0)y)$ for all $x$, $y$, which is enough to give a selfadjoint $L=P'(0)$ if $L$ is bounded. So, I'd have to say yes in that case.

Comment: @user167575 : If $P$ is a bounded selfadjoint $C^{0}$ semigroup, then $P'(0)=L$ is symmetric on its domain by the previous comment, and $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t\lambda}P(t)xdt= (\lambda I - L)^{-1}x$ exists for $\Re\lambda > 0$, which is enough to force $L$ be selfadjoint and negative. So $-L$ will be a positive selfadjoint operator in that case. I believe that is correct.